# The setHex method of PHP MapScript doesn't work

Tags: php, mapserver

I'm using PHP MapScript 6.4 to interact with my Mapfile.
I try to use the `setHex()` colorObj method like that:

```
$oStyle->color->setHex($color);
```

Where `$color` is an hexadecimal value as we can see in my logs
[image: setHex() error]

But regarding the MapScript https://mapserver.org/mapscript/php/phpmapscript.html#colorObj I can use `setHex()` method.

It works perfectly fine with `$oStyle->color->setRGB(255,255,255);` for example, so why not `setHex()`?

I'm using MapScript 6.4, I have looked at the 6.0.1 release documentation and the `setHex()` method exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for using MapServer !  Here are some important points:

- setHex() is not available in MapServer 6.x for PHP MapScript: you can find the documentation for your exact version by:

  - going to https://mapserver.org
  - goto "Documentation" https://mapserver.org/documentation.html
  - at the top click on "Documentation for earlier versions of MapServer can be found on the Download page"
  - there you can see the various versions you can download for the documentation, such as 6.4 https://mapserver.org/pdf/MapServer-64.pdf
  - search for "setHex" and you will only find it only inside the SWIG MapScript section
- setHex() and toHex() for PHP MapScript were added to the MapServer 7.0.0 release (ticket: https://github.com/MapServer/MapServer/pull/5078)
- I've now added the text "new in version 7.0.0" to the colorObj for those methods at https://mapserver.org/mapscript/php/phpmapscript.html#colorobj

Please also note:

- there was a major vulnerability found in PHP MapScript recently (6.4.4 and 7.4.4 were released for this reason)
- PHP MapScript is unsupported/unmaintained, and therefore SWIG MapScript is recommended moving forward (which has full PHP7 support)

Thanks for using MapServer.   Happy (fast) mapserving!

-Jeff McKenna